# Git branches with different directory structure

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff, git-config

I have repository ABC with branches master, test and development.

master directory structure has:

- folder1
- folder2
- folder3
- ...
- .gitignore
- README.md

test branch has similar structure:

- test.folder1
- test.folder2
- test.folder3
- onlytestfile.txt
- ...
- .gitignore
- README.md

development branch has similar structure:

- dev.folder1
- dev.folder2
- dev.folder3
- onlydevfile.txt
- ...
- .gitignore
- README.md

All branches have exactly the same content inside the folders. Commits and changes go to development first and then merge into test then into master. Question is how do I do these merges between branches with the difference in the folder name structure?

Answer (score 1):

> *Question is how do I do these merges between branches with the difference in the folder name structure?*

You rename the directories to match, commit, and then merge.

This is not a viable workflow, and it's not an efficient use of branches.

Since the branches already keep your dev, test, and presumably production versions separate, there's no need to change the directory names. Name the same things the same in all branches and the problem goes away.

---

As for the `onlytestfile.txt`, and `onlydevfile.txt` you can't exclude files from a merge. You have to merge everything. So you either have to delete it and commit before merging, or `git merge --no-commit` and manually delete the file yourself (which someone will inevitably forget to do), or come up with a better strategy. I suggest the last one.

I presume this is configuration information. There are various better strategies for storing the config for multiple environments, and [I lay one out in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50322416/14660).

Comment: What you are saying here is not a valid point. Different applications have different file structure. Typically, I do what you are saying in your answer but that does not mean that the question is invalid.

Comment: @Kal Yes, the question is quite valid, it comes up a lot, and I gave an answer to it. We also recognize when questions are [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); you're asking about a solution, not your problem which is configuration management and version control. There are better solutions to your problem that are simpler, less error prone, and works with Git, not against it. By asking experts we can recognize this and offer a deeper answer. You got two answers for the price of one. :)

Comment: @Kal If there's extra circumstances about your situation where the usual solutions don't apply, please add it to your question so we can provide answers that fit better.

Comment: @Kal - What Schwern is saying here *is* a valid point. As you said "All branches have exactly the same content inside the folders", then it is not a feasible solution to change those folders' names across branches - because then `git` can't tell what you're expecting. If you have deployment needs that require working copies to use different filenames, that is a problem best solved outside the source control tool.  Any persistent difference between branches will make merging across the branches into a problem.